# Cannot read properties of undefined - javascript class

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mobx

I wanted to try mobx for react state management, however, I can't get this to work. I have this simple store for storing just a number called counter. You can increment/decrement it, and increse it by x. I have this file store.js for storing the state:

```
import { action, makeObservable, observable } from "mobx";


class CounterStore {
    counter = 0;

    constructor() {
        makeObservable(this, {
            counter: observable,
            increment: action,
            decrement: action,
            increase: action
        });
      
    }

    increment() {
        this.counter++;
    }

    decrement() {
        this.counter--;
    }

    increase(value) {
        this.counter = this.counter + value;
    }
}

const store = new CounterStore();

export default store;
```

And then I have this component named Counter inside Counter.js, which executes the methods like increment and decrement for the store

```
import { useRef } from "react";
import classes from './Counter.module.css'
import store from "../store";

function Counter() {

    const numberInput = useRef();

    const increaseHandler = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault(); 
        if (numberInput.current.value === ''){
            return;
        }
        store.increase(parseInt(numberInput.current.value))
    };
    return (
        <div>
            <div className={classes.counter}>{store.counter}</div>
            <div className={classes.row}>
                <button className={classes.btn} onClick={store.increment}>Increment</button>
                <button className={classes.btn} onClick={store.decrement}>Decrement</button>
            </div>
            <form className={classes.row} onSubmit={increaseHandler}>
                <button className={classes.btn}>Increase by x</button>
                <input className={classes.input} required="true " type="number" ref={numberInput} />
            </form>

        </div>
    );
}

export default Counter;
```

But when i press the button, I always get

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'counter') at increment
```

How can the counter possibly be undefined? I already export the instantiated store.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your function is losing context (`this`), you need to [read about it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) to understand how it works. You destructured this function from the store and it is not bound to it anymore.

The most common way is to define all actions as arrow functions, like that:

```
    // Use arrow function to define methods
    increment = () => {
        this.counter++;
    }

    decrement = () => {
        this.counter--;
    }

    increase = (value) => {
        this.counter = this.counter + value;
    }
```

That way you don't need to worry about the context, it will be automatically bound to the current class.

Comment: Arrow functions for methods are not recommended because this will create the method as a value and the methods will be re-created for each instance.